# Array to string conversion on array_map

Tags: php, posts, wp-query

I'm using array_map to sort out an array with all of my _octopud_id's.

`var_dump($offices)`: Returns the following:

```
array (size=500)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '1382' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '1330' (length=4)
```

I need to input that array integer into the 'employees/' section but I can't figure out how - If I hardcode `employees/6` I get the following result:

```
object(stdClass)[14592]
  public 'id' => int 6
```

What could I be doing wrong? I keep getting the `Notice: Array to string conversion` error on the $results = line.

```
/* Return an array of _octopus_ids */
$offices = array_map(
    function($post) {
        return array(
            'id' => get_post_meta($post->ID, '_octopus_id', true),
        );
    },
    $query->posts
);

var_dump($offices);

$results = $octopus->get_all('employee/' . implode($offices));
var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at `$offices`:

```
array (size=500)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '1382' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '1330' (length=4)
```

That is not an array of IDs. It's an array *of arrays*. `$offices[0]` is not `'1382'`. It's an array. So `implode()` on `$offices` is trying to concatenate arrays, which is what's causing your error.

The cause of the error is how you've used `array_map`. If you want to return this meta value for each post in an array, then you should only return the value, not a new array:

```
$offices = array_map(
    function($post) {
        return get_post_meta($post->ID, '_octopus_id', true);
    },
    $query->posts
);
```

Now `$offices` will be an array of IDs, which can be imploded.

Comment: thanks so much! Since I want to be able to keep the id as an array with all the values, how would I retrieve just the `string '1382'` numeric value and use that?